# C#WPFアプリでAlphaTabとMIDIを統合し、ドラムパートの再生タイミングを合わせるには？

Tags: c#, wpf

私はC#WPFアプリで、guitapro(gp)ファイルの解析に [AlphaTab](https://alphatab.net/docs/introduction) (1.3.0)を使用しています。gpファイルのスコアからドラムパート（つまり、どのタイミングでドラムのどの部分がどう演奏されているか）を独自に視覚的に表示したいと考えています。ざっくり言うと、一般的な楽譜データのフォーマットから音楽ゲームのようにノートを視覚化したいということです。

現在、ドラムパートの抽出は成功しており、その中身は再生位置の時間とパートの文字列です。その後、AlphaSynthを使用してmidiの再生に合わせてドラムの全パートが叩かれるタイミングを確認しようとしています。方法は、AlphaTab.Synth.AlphaSynthクラスのplayer.PositionChanged.Onから再生位置が変更されるたびに再生位置を取得し、その時間とドラムパートに保存されたデータQueueの時間を比較してタイミングを確認するものです。

しかし、現在の実装ではタイミングが大きくずれていることがわかりました。具体的には、player.PositionChanged.Onの時間取得が40ミリ秒おきであり、これがドラムパートに保存されている再生位置と一致しない状況です。

- midiの再生時間に合わせて比較を行うことそのもの
- そもそもの話、リアルタイムでタイミングの合成処理を行う必要がない
  ことを考慮すると現在のデータ処理が非効率である可能性があります。

再生タイミングを合わせるための効果的な方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

現在のドラムパートのデータは以下のクラスに保存されています。

```
    public class BeatInfo
    {
        public double StartTime { get; set; }
        public List<string> DrumParts { get; set; } // DrumPartをList<string>に変更
    }
```

また、midiプレイヤーを作成するメソッドは以下の通りです。

```
        public AlphaTab.Synth.AlphaSynth CreateAndLoadPlayer()
        {
            string soundFontPath = サウンドフォントのパス, "ここにサウンドフォント");

            byte[] soundFontData = File.ReadAllBytes(soundFontPath);
            var player = new AlphaTab.Synth.AlphaSynth(new NAudioSynthOutput(), 1000);
            player.LoadSoundFont(soundFontData, false);
            player.LoadMidiFile(drumTrackMidiFile);
            return player;
        }
```

そして、midiの再生に合わせてドラムパートをGUIに視覚的に表示するメソッドは以下の通りです。

```
private void DT_PlayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            // 0秒のイベントが存在する限り、それらをすべて削除します
            while (BeatInfosQueue.Count > 0 && Math.Abs(BeatInfosQueue.Peek().StartTime) < 0.01)
            {
                BeatInfosQueue.Dequeue();
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(BeatInfosQueue);
            _player = _parser.CreateAndLoadPlayer();
  
            // MIDIファイルを再生します
            _player.Play();
            _player.PositionChanged.On(args =>
            {
                // 現在の再生位置を取得します
                double timePosition = args.CurrentTime;

                // 再生位置をログに出力します
                Debug.WriteLine(timePosition);
                Debug.WriteLine(BeatInfosQueue.Peek().StartTime);

                // ドラムのイベントのタイミングとtimePositionを比較します
                if (BeatInfosQueue.Count > 0 && Math.Abs(timePosition - BeatInfosQueue.Peek().StartTime) < 30)
                {
                    // UIスレッドでラベルを更新します
                    DrumLabel.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        DrumLabel.Content = "●";
                    });
                    BeatInfosQueue.Dequeue(); // イベントをキューから削除します
                }
                else
                {
                    // UIスレッドでラベルを更新します
                    DrumLabel.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        DrumLabel.Content = "〇";
                    });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

私が取得してたデータそのものが再生位置ではなく、midiティックの位置を取得していました。